# Mysql to get the current date with time 23:59:59

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

If I execute

```
select current_date;
```

This will give the current date.

What if I have to get the current date with 23:59:59 , So that it will be end of the day.

In SQL Server I used

```
Select CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) + ' 23:59:59' AS   
DATETIME;
```

Answer (score 12):

One method is to add seconds:

```
select date_add(CURDATE(), interval 24*60*60 - 1 second)
```

Another method is `addtime()`:

```
select addtime(CURDATE(), '23:59:59')
```

Comment: select addtime(CURDATE(), '23:59:59') does not work. Just returns 23:59:59 without date.

Answer (score 8):

Adding interval of 1 day - 1 second] would only work if the datetime / timestamp in question has time set to 00:00:00 (that's the case of `CURDATE()` and `CURRENT_DATE`).

However, if you need to work with datetime / timestamp set to, for example, `2021-08-05 02:00:00`, the aforementioned method would yield `2021-08-06 01:59:59`.

In such case, you may use DATE_FORMAT:

```sql
SELECT expire_at, DATE_FORMAT(expire_at, "%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59")
FROM coupons;
```

(tested on MySQL 8.0.18)